# 1978 disco song with lyrics "Keep on, keep on, keep on dancing"

Tags: identify-this-song, compilations

I'm looking for a 1978-1979 disco song where the lyrics went "Keep on, keep on, keep on dancing". I believe it was on a compilation cassette in 1978 where one of the last songs was Exile's "Kiss you all over", but I'm not sure about the last. Can you help me?

Comment: Got to give it up.... Marin Gaye

Comment: Isn't that lyric in *every* disco song from the 70s?

Comment: Could be heatwave - boogie nights

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it’s [Boney M's *Dancing in the Streets*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZM7hD8RE8k) (the “keep on, keep on” bit starts at 2:48).

Answer (score 2):

I think it very well could be "[Dance, Dance, Dance (Yowsah, Yowsah, Yowsah)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faiwblIEvB8)", by Chic, which appeared on a few compilations with Exile's "Kiss You All Over" in 1978 - 1979, one of which was [*Action Replay*](https://www.discogs.com/Various-Action-Replay/release/2061284), where "Kiss You All Over" was 3rd to last song, but the compilation was on vinyl.

Answer (score 2):

How about The Bay City Rollers - Keep On Dancin'?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5m_Oyi4BxP4

Answer (score 2):

I believe the song you are looking for is [Gary's Gang - *Keep on Dancin'*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkoS962Fd8A). It topped out on the Billboard at no. 41 in 1978.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be [*I Gotta Keep Dancing*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOyMP_Nlpvs) by Carrie Lucas in 1977 on the album *Simply Carrie*.

The lyrics have several times:

> **Keep on dancing** Do do do, yeah, yeah, yeah
>
> CHORUS
>   **I gotta keep dancing** (keep dancing)
>   Smiling (keep smiling)
>   To keep from breaking apart
>   **I gotta keep dancing** (keep dancing)
>   Smiling (keep smiling)
>   To cover up my broken heart

Answer (score 0):

It's Chic - Dance Dance Dance (Yowsah! Yowsah! Yowsah!)from the 70's disco era of music.

I have the original and extended version in my crates.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer which is not this song...